# jQuery scroll to top stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know my jQuery is working (my `console.log` statement prints) and I even got this code to run earlier.  I disconnected from the internet and poof the jQuery scroll to top feature doesnt work.  Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#back_to_top').on('click', function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        console.log('back to top tab clicked');
    });
});
```

But the page doesnt animate when I click the tab, given either method in the code block.

Thoughts?

**EDIT**

this block of code was preventing it from working, not sure why...

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
 }
```

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle of this

Comment: Clear your browser cache …

Comment: Your function seems to be ok. Either you're using the same id twice("#back_to_top") on two or more elements, or you forgot the id on the button( since the fiddle uses body) or your button is behind something and does not get clicked. Or your page needs refresh

Comment: i cleared the cache, and the log statement works, so the button is def on the top of the dom (it receives the click).  it works in firefox too, but not chrome.....any other thoughts?